# JavaScript Event function runs one every page load

Tags: javascript

I put an event javascript function inside the HTML `body` section of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CookiebotCallback_OnAccept() {
        window.location.reload(true);
        if (Cookiebot.consent.statistics)
        {

        }
    }
</script>
```

This script causes an infinite refresh because the function run every time the page is loaded. What can I do to make this function only run when it is called and not automatically every page load?

Comment: Is that the only code inside those script tags?

Comment: Where is `CookiebotCallback_OnAccept` invoked?

Comment: Give us all your code if you need help, this one doesnt do anything

Comment: I tried replicating your issue on Codepen but didn't run into any problem. Here's a link to the Pen: https://codepen.io/DaneTheory/pen/GdrmdR

Could you please post the rest of your code please? Where is `CookiebotCallback_OnAccept()` being invoked? Then, if/when it is being invoked, you immediately call `window.location.reload(true);`. Did you mean to add the bit within your `if` statement?

Comment: @AnimeshKumar yes

Comment: @sjahan "The asynchronous callback is triggered when the user clicks the accept-button of the cookie consent dialog and whenever a consented user loads a page."

Comment: `CookiebotCallback_OnAccept()` is being invoked somewhere. Check the rest of your codebase

Comment: @DaneTheory yeh, now I see it, when a consent user loads a page.

Comment: @DaneTheory I need to search for event only after clicking "accept"

Comment: You can create a function that runs immediately as the page is loaded using native DOM events. Then, invoke your logic to run after the click event occurs

Comment: You do realize the logic `if (Cookiebot.consent.statistics)` will never get run right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to deal with manipulating cookies, or any other hacky solutions. JavaScript offers a few native event listeners for verifying that the document has been successfully loaded. Essentially your three options are:

```
Inline HTML example
1. <body onload='fooBar()'>

Native DOM events that can be invoked within an HTML snippet,
or more preferably, within there own parent function to offer
more fine grained control over invocation.
2. document.onload = ()=>
3. window.onload = ()=> 
    i.e:
        const foo = () => document.onload
        const bar = () => window.onload

     Invoking them anywhere within you code base as necesary without 
     rigidly coupling your JavaScript code within your HTML
```

The preferred method is `window.onload` as the `document` isn't completely honest about when it's been loaded.

Following the logic you have above using the inline approach, here's a working alternative:

```
// Add the following HTML immediately after your opening `body` tag.
// This ensures no competing JS scripts can run before the one we have 
// here.
<script type="text/javascript">

    (() => {
      const runMeAfterPageLoad = () => 
        Cookiebot.consent.statistics ? // If true logic here : null

        if (window.addEventListener) {
          window.addEventListener('load', runMeAfterPageLoad, false)
        }
        else if (window.attachEvent) {
         window.attachEvent('onload', runMeAfterPageLoad)
        }
        else window.onload = runMeAfterPageLoad
    })()

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution is creating a flag variable in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`, then check if has the variable already, skip calling reload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function CookiebotCallback_OnAccept() {
      if(!sessionStorage.getItem('isReloaded')) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('isReloaded', true);

        window.location.reload(true);

        if (Cookiebot.consent.statistics)
        {

        }
      }
    }
</script>
// you can also clear the variable to trigger the reload again.
// By: sessionStorage.removeItem('isReloaded');
// Note: the sessionStorage will be cleared each time you close the browser, 
// while localStorage is only by uninstalled the browser or manually.
```

Comment: You do realize the logic `if (Cookiebot.consent.statistics)...` will never get run right? You solve his question, but just pointing it out.

Comment: @Popmedic I just copied the code of the author, and I think it should run normally, since `JS` is asynchronous :D.

Comment: p/s: @Popmedic you can try it yourself, by putting `sessionStorage.setItem('thisIsSession','should be fine')` after `.reload()` code, then you can find it in `sessionStorage`, even the browser reloaded.

Comment: p/s: but I agree with you, we shouldn't put the .`reload()` at the beginning of the function. He just got luck because the function has no ajax/promise calling :D